# How to set navigation params properly

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I use react-navigation for navigation in my app. I have some modal view (*SomeComponent*) and I wanna set custom title during presenting animation. The problem is that title is changing but after presenting animation is finished.

I've tried set params in other component lifecycle callback but it didn't work. 
*I don't want to set this parameter with navigate function* because I don't have full data to set it.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: navigation.getParam("customTitle"),
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({ customTitle: "Some custom title" })
    } 
}
```

I wanna set title before animation is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the params in the `getDerivedStateFromProps` method as this is the method that is fired after the constructor and before any render methods

Comment: Doesn't work. It looks that *navigation.setParams* refreshes navigationOptions after animation is finished.